# How to find holiday effect on revenue?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, python

I have 2 datasets from 2013-2017 for each day.
a) Revenue generated by Locations and date.
b) Holiday name and date

I would like to know how each holiday is impacting the revenue by location.
I am confused about what method to use!
Should 3-Sigma rule or Bollinger plot be enough or should I try spline regression or something else?
FYI I am using python for this analysis.

Comment: Do you have readings for every day for every location ?. If you do it is possible to form a model where day-of-the-week , day-of-the-month , month-of-the-year et al can be used to identify lead, contemporary and lag effects for each holiday while conditioning for level/step shifts and anomalies and any short-term memory. important. One can optionally specify the holidays of interest.

Comment: Yes, I have everyday data from 2013-2017. I have tried Moving Average, Weighted Moving average, Cubic Spline regression. Not sure my cubic spline interpolation is correct or not if anyone wants I can paste the code here. Should I try Holt-Winters and ARIMA too?

Comment: Probably not as hw and arima do not consider the kind of day that is in play although conceivably they could be constructively extended to consider the features I previously mentioned. .... Why don't you post the data for 1 location  and I will try and walk you through the art of the possible ... most probably not available to you in python though but perhaps educational and informative as to what can be done and perhaps motivational